# Может ли выражение соответствующее шаблону ^[a-z\d-]+$ быть SQL-иньекцией?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Может ли выражение соответствующее шаблону быть SQL-иньекцией?

```
preg_match('/^[a-z\d-]+$/', $var)
```

SQL-запрос:

```
"SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `col` = '$var'"
```

Comment: Не может. Но подставляемые параметры (bind_param) надо использовать не только для защиты от инъекций но и для увеличения быстродействия. _Никогда_ не вставляйте параметры в текст запроса

Comment: @Mike это должен был быть ответ

Comment: @Mike Но ведь если запрос всего один bind_param не даст увеличения быстродействия?

Comment: @Mike, подготовленные запросы не попадают в кэш запросов, поэтому есть ли увеличение быстродействия или нет, нужно разбираться в каждом конкретном случае. Если кэш запросов включен и он суперэффективен, можно и потерять в производительности.

Comment: Если запрос совсем один, скрипт один раз выполнится и в ближайшие часы подобный скрипт выполнятся не будет - то конечно пофиг. Но если ожидаются другие запуски этого приложения то поможет. MySQL не надо будет заново строить план выполнения запроса, он сможет из кеша взять

Comment: @cheops Запуск регулярки preg_match в любом случае накладнее одного bind_param :) ну если конечно драйвера и библиотека в php не кривые, что вряд ли

Comment: Да не. всё нормально. Какие такие параметры? Не надо параметров. Меньше параметров, быстрее пхп-истов будут гнать из интернета. Странно что до сих пор не выгнали.

Comment: @Sergey Я почему то думал что подготовленные запросы эффективны если в скрипте в подряд выполняются несколько одинаковых запросов (оно и логично - создал шаблон, а дальше его используешь - MySQL оптимизирует запрос любой сложности только один раз, а приложение запускает на выполнение уже подготовленный шаблон). А вы тут говорите что мол и для единичного запроса к БД надо использовать подготовленные запросы. Как 2 запроса к БД могут быть эффективнее чем 1?

Comment: @Mike Разве MySQL сохраняет подготовленные запросы за пределами одного соединения?

Comment: Вы эффективность наносекундомером меряете? Почуюствуете разницу между пятью минутами и пятю минутами плюс двадцать пять миллисекунд? Ничего страшного не случается даже когда на каждый запрос устанавливать новое соединение с базой данных. А ведь именно так работают пхп безо всяких там фаст-цги.

Comment: Просто оставлю это здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/149613/

Comment: Нашли на чём экономить, блин.))

Comment: @Mike preg_match накладнее чем подключение к БД и направление к ней двух запросов? По-моему вы ошибаетесь.

Comment: @Khipster Я про подключение ничего не говорил. Вы его и так и так будете делать. Все отличие в использовании одной функции bind_param, и она - это не обращение к БД. Обращение происходит при prepare и execute. Причем если вы используете функцию query, то она внутри так же состоит из этих prepare и execute, просто скрытых от вас. так что разница только в bind, который происходит внутри php, помечает переменную для последующей передаче драйверу БД

Answer (score 1):

Инъекции быть не должно, но лучше использовать стандартные подготовленные выражения с плейсхолдерами. Хотябы для того, чтобы не изобретать новую регулярку для нового входящего параметра.

**Edited**: С производительностью подготовленных выражений конкретно в PHP всё сложно. Теоретически они могут дать выигрыш. Надо учесть, что обычно соединение с базой создаётся заново при каждом http-запросе и что по умолчанию pdo_mysql эмулирует prepared statement на клиентской стороне.
Если об этом знать, то возможно скорость будет *дополнительным* аргументом в пользу PS.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617057/does-pdo-always-use-emulated-prepared-statements-by-default
- https://habrahabr.ru/post/149613/

Comment: Я вот этого мифа не понимаю, если пользовательский ввод подставляется в SQL-запрос в качестве параметра (в кавычках) и экранируется функцией mysqli_real_escape_string то о каких SQL-иньекциях может идти речь? Использование подготовленных запросов для защиты от SQL-иньекций напоминает забивание гвоздей микроскопом, ведь этот инструмент создан для других целей - оптимизация работы с БД при массовом направлении однотипных запросов.

Comment: Но это же удобно! В конце концов это просто красиво :)